# Mocking WindsorContainer to test the ComponentRegistration

Tags: c#, moq, castle-windsor

I'm using the Castle.Windsor 4.1.1 and I have such a registration:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IMessageMappingManager>().ImplementedBy<MessageMappingManager>());
```

Now I want to test if the registration works well, therefore I Mocked a _container using Moq 4.10.0:

```
_container = new Mock<IWindsorContainer>();
```

Now I want to test the registration like this:

```
_container.Verify(f => f.Register(Component.For<IMessageMappingManager>().ImplementedBy<MessageMappingManager>()), Times.Once);
```

Or like this:

```
_container.Verify(f=>f.Register(It.IsAny<ComponentRegistration<IMessageMappingManager>().ImplementedBy<MessageMappingManager>()>()), Times.Once);
```

But none of them work.
Anybody can help with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit test from your answer tests nothing.  The first problem is that you are mocking out your system under test.

The whole point to test your implementation of the system under test.

Then your only test is that the call to the mocked object happened. It's easy enough to verify that actual registration occurred.

This example uses installers, since I use them to cleanup a lot of registration code.

```
public class EmailInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For(typeof(IResolveApplicationPath))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(ApplicationPathResolver))
                .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);

        container
            .Register(Component.For(typeof(IGenerateEmailMessage)).ImplementedBy(typeof(EmailMessageGenerator))
                .LifeStyle
                .PerWebRequest);

        container
            .Register(Component.For(typeof(ISendEmail)).ImplementedBy(typeof(EmailSender))
                .LifeStyle
                .PerWebRequest);

        container.Register(
            Component.For<NotificationConfigurationSection>()
                .UsingFactoryMethod(
                    kernel =>
                        kernel.Resolve<IConfigurationManager>()
                            .GetSection<NotificationConfigurationSection>("notificationSettings")));

    }
}
```

Then my test looks like

```
    public class WhenInstallingEmailComponents : SpecificationBase
    {
        private IWindsorContainer _sut;

        protected override void Given()
        {
            _sut = new WindsorContainer();
        }

        protected override void When()
        {
            _sut.Install(new EmailInstaller());
        }

        [Then]
        public void ShouldConfigureEmailSender()
        {
            var handler = _sut
                .GetHandlersFor(typeof(ISendEmail))
                .Single(imp => imp.ComponentModel.Implementation == typeof(EmailSender));

            Assert.That(handler, Is.Not.Null);
        }

        [Then]
        public void ShouldConfigureEmailGenerator()
        {
            var handler = _sut
                .GetHandlersFor(typeof(IGenerateEmailMessage))
                .Single(imp => imp.ComponentModel.Implementation == typeof(EmailMessageGenerator));

            Assert.That(handler, Is.Not.Null);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the GetHandlersFor extension method

```
public static class WindsorTestingExtensions
{
    public static IHandler[] GetAllHandlers(this IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        return container.GetHandlersFor(typeof(object));
    }

    public static IHandler[] GetHandlersFor(this IWindsorContainer container, Type type)
    {
        return container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(type);
    }

    public static Type[] GetImplementationTypesFor(this IWindsorContainer container, Type type)
    {
        return container.GetHandlersFor(type)
            .Select(h => h.ComponentModel.Implementation)
            .OrderBy(t => t.Name)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

I use a base class SpecficicationBase to make my unit tests read like a BDD style test, but you should be able to understand what's going on.

1. Instantiate your container
2. Call the installer to register your components.
3. Inspect the container for implementation types for your interfaces.

Here's a good [link](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/mvc-tutorial-part-3a-testing-your-first-installer.md) from the Castle project on how to test your registration code.